# Doing a replacement using a regular expression for a string containing !, followed by some characters, followed by an = character

Tags: javascript, regex

In JavaScript, I was wondering what the best regular expression is for doing a replacement in this situation.

I have a string, uri, which look like this:

```
uri = '/somestring!parameter=.598427fc&prop=someImage';
```

There might be any number of parameters in the string. But there would only be one `!parameter=value`.

In this case, I would like to replace the `!parameter=` with `?paramater=`.

If the parameter was always the same, for example `!loc=value` I could do

```
if (uri.indexOf('!loc=') != -1) uri = uri.replace('!loc=', '?loc=');
```

But what follows the ! might be something other parameter. It might be !id=, or it might be !u= or something else.

So I was wondering what a good regular expression is that I might use to represent ! followed by any number of characters, followed by =, and do the replacement in that case.

Thanks,

doug

Comment: What sort of regex have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess any of the following expressions,

```
!(?=\w*=)
!(?=\w+=)
!(?=[a-z]+=)
!(?=[a-z]*=)
```

being replaced with a `?` might simply work OK here:

#### [RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/ZyAIU1/1/)

```js
const regex = /!(?=[a-z]+=)/gi;
const str = `/somestring!parameter=.598427fc&prop=someImag`;
const subst = `?`;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

---

If you wish to simplify/update/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/I4AONw/1/). You can watch the matching steps or modify them in [this debugger link](https://regex101.com/r/I4AONw/1/debugger), if you'd be interested. The debugger demonstrates that how [a RegEx engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) might step by step consume some sample input strings and would perform the matching process.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: I was under the impression that `parameter` was a placeholder, or a replace would do this fine - as such, would `!(?=\w*\b)` not work better?